# Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic such that $|f(z)| <1$ in the ball $B(0,1)$ with $f(\alpha) \neq 0$ for some $\alpha \in B(0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic such that $|f(z)| <1$ in the ball $B(0,1)$ with $f(\alpha) \neq 0$ for some $\alpha \in B(0,1)$. Show that there exists a function $g$, analytic and satisfies the condition $|g(z)| <1$ in $B(0,1)$ with $$|g^{'}(\alpha)| > |f^{'}(\alpha)|$$

Hint : Consider a similar function similar to $$B(z) = \dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$$

I found this question on one of my past year papers, but i have no idea how to do it, however i have not learnt maximum modulus principle and series expansion (laurent etc) in complex analysis yet. So may i ask if this question needs knowledge outside of contour integrals, if yes i will leave it till next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=f(\alpha )\ne 0$ and consider a function
$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{1-\bar{a}f(z)}.$$
Since $|f(z)|<1$ and $|a|<1$, $g$ satisfies $|g(z)|<1$ in $B(0,1)$. Then
\begin{align}
g^\prime(z)&= \frac{f^\prime(z)(1-\bar{a}f(z))-(f(z)-a)(-\bar{a}f^\prime(z))}{(1-\bar{a}f(z))^2}  \\
&=\frac{(1-|a|^2)f^\prime(z)}{(1-\bar{a}f(z))^2} .
\end{align}
Hence we have $$
|g^\prime(\alpha )|=\frac{|f^\prime(\alpha )|}{1-|a|^2}>|f^\prime(\alpha )|.$$